# Create A Random String with constraints in C++

Tags: c++, random

I want to create a random string of length m*j where m=4,j=3 for example.
I did this

```
static const char alphanum[] = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
return alphanum[rand() % stringLength]
```

I kept the stringlength=3 so that the returned value consists of only first three alphabets (A,B,C) in a random order of length 20

What I want to do now is to have a random string which has A only 3 times B only 4 times and C only 3 times.
How to apply these constraints?
Counters?

Hi,
   I did something similar as suggested in the answer. Here is the Code

```
static const char alphanum[] = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
//Function which generates a random character
char GetRandom(int Position){
    return alphanum[rand() % Position];
}
//******************************************************************************
//                          MAIN
//******************************************************************************
int main()
{
    //Assuming a 3 machines 3 jobs scenario. So chromosome
    int Jobs=4;
    int Machines=3;
    int ChromLength=Jobs*Machines;
    int StringLength=Jobs;
    int Counter[Jobs],i;
    char C;
    char Chromosome[(ChromLength-1)];
    //Seeding
    srand(time(0));
    //Init array
    for(int Cnt=0;Cnt<Jobs;Cnt++)
        Counter[Cnt]=0;
    //Test
    //Fill the array
    for(i=0;i<ChromLength;)
    {
        //Get the Character
        C=GetRandom(StringLength);
        cout<<"Char:"<<C<<endl;
        //Check which character is returend
        for(int j=0;j<StringLength;j++)
        {
            if(C==alphanum[j])
            {
                Counter[j]++;
                cout<<"I am in J "<<j<<" Char:"<<C<<endl;
                if(Counter[j]==Jobs)
                    break;
                else
                {
                    Chromosome[i]=C;
                    cout<<"I:"<<i<<endl;
                    i++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    cout<<Chromosome;

    return 0;
}
```

But the output is having some trailing characters can't understand what they are
Here is a screenshot
[image: screenshot]

Comment: Why dd you add the C and OOP tags?

Comment: The reason you have the junk at the end of your string is you didn't NULL terminate it.

Comment: Thank you @RetiredNinja I am getting a proper result now :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recently needed to do something like that, so I came up with this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
#include <vector>
#include <cctype>
#include <algorithm>
```

First we have the function that returns a random char.

```
unsigned seed1 = std::chrono::system_clock::now().time_since_epoch().count();
/* or try this:
std::random_device rd; 
auto seed1= rd();
*/
std::minstd_rand0 g1 (seed1);
static const std::string alphabet = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
std::uniform_int_distribution<int> dist(0, alphabet.size()-1);

char get_random_char() {
    return alphabet[dist(g1)];
}
```

Then this function gets random chars and rejects those that do not match the predicate. The loop stops when all characters satisfy the predicate.

```
    template <class Pred>
    std::string generate_string(int length, Pred pred) {
        int index = 0;
        std::string final = "";
        while (true) {
           char current = get_random_char();
           if (!pred(index, current)) continue;

           final += current;

           index++;
           if (index >= length) break;
        }
        return final;
    }
```

Our predicate here is passed in as a lambda. For simplicity, I count the number of times A, B and C have already showed up and return false if the current character is any one of them and the count is too high.

```
int main() {
    int A_count = 0;
    int B_count = 0;
    int C_count = 0;

    std::cout << generate_string(20, [&] (int i, char c) {
            if (c == 'A') A_count++;
            if (c == 'B') B_count++;
            if (c == 'C') C_count++;
            if (A_count > 3 && c == 'A') return false;
            if (B_count > 4 && c == 'B') return false;
            if (C_count > 3 && c == 'C') return false;
            return true;
    });

    return 0;
}
```

And a sanity check:

```
std::string test = generate_string(1000, [&] (int i, char c) {
        if (c == 'A') A_count++;
        if (c == 'B') B_count++;
        if (c == 'C') C_count++;
        if (A_count > 3 && c == 'A') return false;
        if (B_count > 4 && c == 'B') return false;
        if (C_count > 3 && c == 'C') return false;
        return true;
    });
std::cout << "A Count: " << std::count(test.begin(), test.end(), 'A') << std::endl;
std::cout << "B Count: " << std::count(test.begin(), test.end(), 'B') << std::endl;
std::cout << "C Count: " << std::count(test.begin(), test.end(), 'C') << std::endl;
```

Outputs:

```
A Count: 3
B Count: 4
C Count: 3
```

Comment: `std::uniform_int_distribution<int> dist(0, alphabet.size());` The interval in the distribution's constructor is closed on both ends, unlike most other STL things. Array indexing may overflow.

Comment: @C.R. I'm trying to fix the kinks right now, there will be a couple of edits to my answer.

Comment: Another advice: with `<random>` the preferred way of generating seed is `std::random_device rd; auto seed=rd();`.

Comment: @C.R. Thanks, my mileage has varied when it comes to generating random numbers, and I picked the solution that gave me consistent results.